# onDisappear not called when a modal View is dismissed

Tags: ios, swiftui

I rely on the SwiftUI's `.onDisappear` to perform some logic but it is not being called when the user dismisses a modally presented view with the swipe gesture. To reproduce

- Present a view modally a "ChildView 1"
- On this view, push a "ChildView 2" as a navigation child
- Swipe down to dismiss the modal view.

The .onDisappear of "ChildView 2" is not called.

**Sample code to reproduce**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShowingModal
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                self.isShowingModal.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show Modal")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingModal) {
            NavigationView {
                ChildView(title: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    let title: Int
    var body: some View {

        NavigationLink(destination: ChildView(title: title + 1)) {
            Text("Show Child")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("View \(title)")


        .onAppear {
            print("onAppear ChildView \(self.title)")
        }
        .onDisappear {
            print("onDisappear ChildView \(self.title)")
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
onAppear ChildView 1
onAppear ChildView 2
onDisappear ChildView 1
```

[image]

Comment: The `.onAppear` is called when view is added to view hierarchy, `.onDisappear` when removed. In your use-case `ChildView 2` is not removed from superview - removed window. In general it is not reliable way to move logic there, just in case.

Comment: @Asperi I think this is the most relevant answer that explains the why.

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for logic to occur when the actual modal is dismissed, you're going to want to call that here, where I print out Modal Dismissed:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShowingModal = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                self.isShowingModal.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show Modal")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingModal) {
            NavigationView {
                ChildView(title: 1)
            }
            .onDisappear {
                print("Modal Dismissed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to mix any logic of the `ChildView` in the `ContentView`. In my `ChildView` I'm establishing a network connection when `.onAppear` is called and would like to close it when the view disappears.

Comment: I'm not using a `NavigationView` _in my_ child view but _outside of it_. There is only one navigation stack that I create when presenting modally. All the ChildViews are pushed on the same stack.

Comment: @Jan sorry, my mistake ... disregard!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShowingModal = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                self.isShowingModal.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show Modal")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingModal) {
            NavigationView {
                ChildView(title: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in this code, you have NavigationView, and when presenting sheet, you push there another NavigationView. This is the source of trouble

You don't need any NavigationView to present modals. If you like to present another modal from modal, you can use

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
         ChildView(title: 1)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State var isShowingModal = false
    let title: Int
    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
                self.isShowingModal.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show Modal \(title)").font(.largeTitle)
            }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingModal) {
            ChildView(title: self.title + 1)

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

UPDATE

from Apple 
**Human Interface Guidelines**

Modality is a design technique that presents content in a temporary mode that’s separate from the user's previous current context and requires an explicit action to exit

Comment: My question is specifically about the case where a navigation is presented modally and then a view is pushed on that navigation

Comment: @Jan in that case, if user dismiss the sheet (modal view) it dismiss it without popping it from navigation stack. if you like that behavior, use it :-) i also suggest you to use instruments to check how memory is allocated and deallocated.

Comment: @Jan see https://swiftui-lab.com/modal-dismiss-gesture/ which could eventually help you to disable dismiss by swipe-down, or pop from navigation stack without standard back button.