# Show leading navigationBarItems button only if shown as a modal

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view that can be shown either as a modal, or simply pushed onto a navigation stack. When it's pushed, it has the back button in the top left, and when it's shown as a modal, I want to add a close button (many of my testers were not easily able to figure out that they could slide down the modal and really expected an explicit close button).

Now, I have multiple problems.

1. How do I figure out if a View is shown modally or not? Or alternatively, if it's not the first view on a navigation stack? In UIKit there are multiple ways to easily do this. Adding a `presentationMode` `@Environment` variable doesn't help, because its `isPresented` value is also true for pushed screens. I could of course pass in a `isModal` variable myself but it seems weird that's the only way?
2. How do I conditionally add a leading navigationBarItem? The problem is that if you give `nil`, even the default back button is hidden.

Code to copy and paste into Xcode and play around with:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var showModal = false

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack(spacing: 20) {
        Button("Open modally") {
          self.showModal = true
        }

        NavigationLink("Push", destination: DetailView(isModal: false))
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Home")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
      NavigationView {
        DetailView(isModal: true)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct DetailView: View {
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
  let isModal: Bool

  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello World")
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail"), displayMode: .inline)
      .navigationBarItems(leading: closeButton, trailing: deleteButton)
  }

  private var closeButton: some View {
    Button(action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {
      Image(systemName: "xmark")
        .frame(height: 36)
    }
  }

  private var deleteButton: some View {
    Button(action: { print("DELETE") }) {
      Image(systemName: "trash")
        .frame(height: 36)
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

If I change `closeButton` to return an optional `AnyView?` and then return `nil` when `isModal` is false, I don't get a back button at all. I also can't call `navigationBarItems` twice, once with a leading and once with a trailing button, because the latter call overrides the first call. I'm kinda stuck here.

Comment: About tracking modality throughout view hierarchy you can consider approach provided in [Dismiss a parent modal in SwiftUI from a NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59825996/12299030) topic

Comment: please, before continue, see why using NavigationView in sheet is wrong idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468040/ondisappear-not-called-when-a-modal-view-is-dismissed/60468606#60468606 If swipe down doesn't work, add some dismiss button, dont use navigation stack

Comment: I am using a NavigationView in the modal because I want to show a title and some buttons in the navigation bar. Not because I am going to push secondary screens onto the modal's nav stack. Seems perfectly fine to me, and not something I want to change.

Comment: in this case, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I managed it. It's not pretty and I am very much open to different suggestions, but it works

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension View {
  func eraseToAnyView() -> AnyView {
    AnyView(self)
  }

  public func conditionalNavigationBarItems(_ condition: Bool, leading: AnyView, trailing: AnyView) -> some View {
    Group {
      if condition {
        self.navigationBarItems(leading: leading, trailing: trailing)
      } else {
        self
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var showModal = false

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack(spacing: 20) {
        Button("Open modally") {
          self.showModal = true
        }

        NavigationLink("Push", destination: DetailView(isModal: false))
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Home")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
      NavigationView {
        DetailView(isModal: true)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct DetailView: View {
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
  let isModal: Bool

  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello World")
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail"), displayMode: .inline)
      .navigationBarItems(trailing: deleteButton)
      .conditionalNavigationBarItems(isModal, leading: closeButton, trailing: deleteButton)
  }

  private var closeButton: AnyView {
    Button(action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {
      Image(systemName: "xmark")
        .frame(height: 36)
    }.eraseToAnyView()
  }

  private var deleteButton: AnyView {
    Button(action: { print("DELETE") }) {
      Image(systemName: "trash")
        .frame(height: 36)
    }.eraseToAnyView()
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Comment: If you change the conditionalNavigationBarItems header to use generics, you no longer need to use the eraseToAnyView extension method: `public func conditionalNavigationBarItems<L, T>(_ condition: Bool, leading: L, trailing: T) -> some View where L : View, T : View`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any trouble, just add Dismiss button to your navigation bar. You only have to rearrange your View hierarchy and there is no need to pass any binding to your DetailView

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sheet = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Button("Open modally") {
                    self.sheet = true
                }

                NavigationLink("Push", destination: DetailView())
            }.navigationBarTitle("Home")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
            NavigationView {
                DetailView().navigationBarTitle("Title").navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                    self.sheet.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                }))
            }
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

You still can dismiss it with swipe down, you can add some buttons (as part of DetailView declaration) ... etc.

When pushed, you have default back button, if shown modaly, you have dismiss
button indeed.

**UPDATE** (based od discussion)

```
.sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            DetailView().navigationBarTitle("Title")
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                    HStack {

                        Button(action: {
                            self.sheet.toggle()
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Dismiss").padding(.horizontal)
                        })
                        Color.clear
                        Button(action: {

                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "trash")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                        })

                    }.frame(width: proxy.size.width)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

finally **I suggest** you to use

```
extension View {
    @available(watchOS, unavailable)
    public func navigationBarItems<L, T>(leading: L?, trailing: T) -> some View where L : View, T : View {
        Group {
            if leading != nil {
                self.navigationBarItems(leading: leading!, trailing: trailing)
            } else {
                self.navigationBarItems(trailing: trailing)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same solution as well at first, but this can't be used when you also want to show a trailing button, as adding the leading `navigationBarItems` inside the sheet gets rid of the trailing item inside the detail view itself. But when all you want is an optional close button, then yes this is a great way to do it!

Comment: @KevinRenskers put all the action buttons in HStack and separate leading and trailing group with spacer.

Comment: @KevinRenskers one more update (View extension) which I've used in my 'today's' project

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we provide `.navigationBarItems(leading: _anything_)`, ie **anything**, the standard back button has gone, so you have to provide your own back button conditionally.

The following approach works (tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

```
    .navigationBarItems(leading: Group {
        if isModal {
            closeButton
        } else {
            // custom back button here calling same dismiss
        }
    }, trailing: deleteButton)
```

**Update:** alternate approach might be as follows (tested in same)

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if isModal {
            Text("Hello")
                .navigationBarItems(leading: closeButton, trailing: deleteButton)
        } else {
            Text("Hello")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: deleteButton)
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Test", displayMode: .inline)
}
```

Comment: Right, but then you have to create your own back button which doesn't fit well with the rest of the pages, animations are different, etc.

Comment: @KevinRenskers, see update with alternate approach.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I ended up with as well, via `conditionalNavigationBarItems` so I don't have to write my whole view hierarchy twice.